# As a beginner, I am running into the following syntax error, Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "." at [2:39]

Tags: sql

```sql
SELECT
  my-data-project-071422.employee_data.employees.name   AS employee_name,
  my-data-project-071422.employee_data.employees.role   AS employee_role,
  my-data-project-071422.employee_data.departments.name AS department_name
FROM 
  my-data-project-071422.employee_data.employees
INNER JOIN
  my-data-project-071422.employee_data.departments ON
  my-data-project-071422.employee_data.department = departments.department_id
```

Comment: It would help everyone, especially you, if you used an [alias](https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-use-aliases-with-sql-join/) in that join.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
my-data-project-071422.employee_data.department = departments.department_id
```

You appear to be trying to join a table to a column of the same table. That makes no sense at all. You need to join a column, typically a primary key, to another column, typically a secondary key, of another table.

You also really need to learn how to use aliases.

I can't be sure, but I am guessing you want something like:

```
SELECT
  emp.name AS employee_name,
  emp.role AS employee_role,
  dep.name AS department_name
FROM 
  my-data-project-071422.employee_data.employees AS emp
INNER JOIN
  my-data-project-071422.employee_data.departments AS dep
    ON dep.department_id = emp.department_id
```

Comment: departments schema

Comment: name
STRING NULLABLE   
department_id
INTEGER NULLABLE

Comment: employees schema name
STRING NULLABLE   
department_id
INTEGER NULLABLE   
role
STRING NULLABLE

Comment: You should add your schema to your question, but I have updated my answer to incorporate it. None of those columns should be NULLABLE, except arguably `employees.role`.